# Share files from the server without data or internet usage

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, server

I have a server and i'll connect using the ssh from my laptop , **Both the server and my laptop are in a same network** ! Is there any way to share files and videos from the server to my local laptop without any internet or data loss , but i don't any cable connection , need this to be wireless ! lets consider the file is over 2 GB which is in the server , i dont want to spend 2 GB data to download from the server , so anyway to get the file from the server where the systems are in the same network !

I need the file to be accessed without spending my data

Comment: Make sure to connect to your server using its local private IP address (often something like `192.168.*.*`).

Comment: @Éric  Thanks for the info , but the issue is  the server is connected to my local machine over ssh using the wireguard , so using the wireguard i am able to ping and connect to the server coz the server is behind another network ! so in this case i'll first connect through the wireguard then i'll use the ssh to connect to the server , now how can i able to get the files without spending the file size data to get the file , coz now i am in the same network right !